# Database design in website that sells tickets for events with Django

Tags: database, django, database-design, django-models

I'm working on a website that sells tickets for events. And I have the following design:

[image: Database draft]

And the (simplified for posting) models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=20)

class Date(models.Model):
    event_start = models.DateTimeField()

    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)

class Ticket_Class(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=20)
    price = models.IntegerField()

    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

1. How should I add a Ticket model? Because a Ticket is for an Event on a particular Date, so I would need to relate a ticket to the relationship between Event and Date
2. A Ticket_Class should also have a "max" field where is stored the maximum tickets available to sell for that particular Ticket_Class on a particular Date. E.g.: Event "Metallica" has Ticket_Class "Field" and Ticket_Class "VIP", both on three different dates. How would I access the number of remaining tickets for a Ticket_Class on a particular Date? Maybe counting how many Tickets are in the Ticket table corresponding to that Event on that Date.

I hope I made myself clear, english is not my first language. Feel free to ask any doubts

Answer (score 2):

I think your design should be something like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=20)

class Date(models.Model):
    event_start = models.DateTimeField()
    event_end= models.DateTimeField()
class Ticket_Class(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=20)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    type= models.CharField(max_lenght=20)

class EventTicketSell(models.Model):
    event= models.ForeignKey(Event)
    date= models.ForeignKey(Date)
    ticket= models.ForeignKey(Ticket_Class)
    max_sellable_tickets= models.IntegerField()
```

Reason for this design is that you can add a event to EventTicketSell class, then assign date and ticket with max sellable tickets.

for adding ticket/date/event:

```
event1= Event(name= "Lion King")
event1.save()
event2= Event(name= "Metallica")
event2.save()

vip_ticket= Ticket_Class(name='VIP', price= 100, type='VIP')
vip_ticket.save()

evening_show= Date(event_start='Date Object', event_end= 'Date Object') # Date Object is like datetime.datetime.now()
evening_show.save()

concert_ticket_sell= EventTicketSell(event=event1, ticket=vip_ticket, date= evening_show, max_sellable_ticket=500)
concert_ticket_sell.save()

movie_ticket_sell= EventTicketSell(event=event2, ticket=vip_ticket, date= evening_show, max_sellable_tickets=500)
movie_ticket_sell.save()
```

This design will keep objects reusable and flexible to modify. For example, if you want to change max_sellable_ticket then:

```
movie_ticket_sell= EventTicketSell.objects.filter(event__name='Lion King', date__event_start= datetime.datetime.now(), ticket__type= 'VIP')[0]

movie_ticket_sell.max_sellable_tickets -= form.cleaned_data['ticket_sold'] #for example we get sold count from form

movie_ticket_sell.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the event needs to have a ticket amount field to verify what the max tickets are.  Then it should have a foreign key relationship with the ticket_class.  In order to make sure you do not exceed the amount of tickets available then you would probably need to use something like the clean method to verify it does not exceed when associating a ticket to an event.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

I'm just looking at this from a high level so maybe I'm missing something.  I'm also unclear why you can't just have the date be a field in the event?

Comment: Because an event can have multiple dates, maybe "Shows" is a better word. Event "The Lion King on Ice" can have Shows on friday, saturday and sunday.